# What is the reason to use observe_field instead of onkeydown in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Is there any good reason why most rails developers use observe_field when they want trigger specific action when text input box is changed, rather then using onkeydown? I would expect, that in most of the cases using observe_field results much more code generated than just using native hook onkeydown.

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: 2.3 but it is meant as general question

Comment: it seems really strange idea to put special object on the page which only observes other event in other object when we already have the hook for this + it is usable without necessarily descending to javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a convenient way rails supplied for the person who doesn't know about javascript, or who doesn't want to write another piece of JavaScript code.

Comment: it is possible to use onkeydown withut writing any javascript - something like: :onkeydown => update_page { |page| page[:item].toggle }